# Google Play Music frequently flashing in notification bar and notification tray

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, google-play-music, google-apps, notification-icons

Recently, Google issued an update for Google Play Music.

Now, I frequently see the Google Play Music icon briefly appearing in the Android notification bar (aka status bar).

It will appear for about a tenth of second, then disappear, then do the same a second later.  This happens on and off throughout the day.

I think it is also flashing up a brief notification in the notification tray, but it's hard to tell, because it just flashes there for less than a second.

This happens when Google Play Music is not even running (although it presumably has some background tasks).

This ***never*** happened before the recent update to Google Play Music.

It's distracting to have this icon sporadically appear.  Also it can cause all the left-side notification bar icons to shift due to this "fluttering" of the Google Play Music icon.

What's going on, and is there a way to fix it?

(Oh, I should mention: I don't want to turn off all notifications for Google Play Music, because they are useful on days it is actually used.)

***Update:*** This symptom has been confirmed by two other Android SE users.

Comment: You could try installing an app such as [Notif Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dvdh.notiflog) or [Notification History](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myd.android.nhistory2) and see if it logs the notification when it flashes up. You should then be able to view the notification information via the app. (I've not used either of these apps so can't promise they'll work)

Answer (score 3):

I also saw thius notification flashing briefly. As far as I can tell, it is related to connectivity changes (switching from WiFi to mobile and vice versa). For the time being, I've disabled notifications for Play Music but hope they'll issue an update to fix this behavior.

Comment: Same here, the only fix I could see is to turn off notification access for the Google Play Music App.